# Is there a difference between string.Split() with a single character vs a one length char array?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any reason to ever use the latter? It just seems like it's saying less with more.

```
text.Split('\t')[0];
text.Split("\t".ToCharArray()).GetValue(0).ToString();
```

I'm wondering if it has something to do with "\t" vs a '\t' in the string being split but other than that I can't think of any justification for the longer version.

Comment: The method is `Split(params char[]? separator)` so both are calling the same thing.  The first just wraps the single char into an array for you versus the second one creating the array manually from a string.  So even if there was more than one character you can do `Split('a', 'b', 'c')` instead of `Split("abc".ToCharArray())`

Comment: Note that's different from using an overload that takes string like `Split(string? separator, StringSplitOptions option)` as that will split on the entire string and not on each individual character.

Comment: Also the `GetValue` and `ToString` are overkill since `Split` returns a array of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. There will probably be no significant performance difference between the two, and there's definitely no behavioral difference, but the second one is certainly a lot more verbose.